# $(document).ready(function () {} function in moov web to build the control with jQuery

Tags: jquery, moovweb, tritium

Where should I be placing my

```
$(document).ready(function () {...});
```

function in moov web to bind the control with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about what are you trying to achieve? It's not clear to me where/what function from jQuery do you want to use on a Moovweb project.

JC